# Single Switch confusion

Tags: electrical, switch

I’ve done a bunch of single switches and then stumbled upon this one. All of my switches were back wired and I switched to side wiring on new ones. Now this switch has the two back wired, ground wire and an additional side wired. My new single switch only has two brass side screws and ground screw. Why is there a third wire? Do I just back wire it or get a new switch specific for this wiring?
[image]

Comment: The person who did that, left too much bare black wire showing.  Those bare wires have power going though them and not insulated.  Should have the insulation at least touching the plastic back of the switch.

Answer (score 6):

The two wires that are close to each other (one back stab and one screwed) are connected together. Someone decided to use the switch to make this connection.

You should get a wire nut, have those two twisted together along with a third one. The third one will go to one brass connector on your new switch. The other (far) black wire will go the to other connector.

Search this SE, you'll find many posts about downsides of backstab connections.

Comment: I think I am following what you are saying. That might be outside of my novice scope. Might call in reinforcements. Thank you!!

Comment: @CourtneyK this is very easy to do. It's called a pig-tail, and you'll find dozens of references to it here and elsewhere on the internet. It's a simple upgrade that you'll feel great about adding to your skill set. Take it on!